# How to define Postgres DB column order in NestJS?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, pgadmin

This is a very minor annoyance, but in my NestJS application I have this entity:

```ts
@Entity({ name: DB_TABLE_NAME_TEST })
export class TestEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Exclude({ toPlainOnly: true }) //hide from response objects
  @ManyToOne(() => AccountEntity, (acct) => acct.id)
  @JoinColumn()
  account: string;

  @Column()
  description: string;

  @Column()
  testerName: string;

  @Column()
  testerEmail: string;

  @Column({ type: 'jsonb', array: false, default: () => "'[]'", nullable: false })
  @Type(() => Array<ITestEvent>)
  eventList: Array<ITestEvent>;

  @Column({ type: 'jsonb', array: false, default: () => "'[]'", nullable: false })
  @Type(() => Array<QuestionLibraryEntity>)
  questionLibraries: Array<QuestionLibraryEntity>;
}
```

When it creates the table for PostgreSQL the columns in pgAdmin appear in a different order

[image: pgAdmin Column Order]

The only reason this is an annoyance is because I have 2 `jsonb` columns and the data in there can be very long, thus is pushes the `accountId` column off the screen. I would prefer to have it right next to the `id` column like I defined it in my NestJS entity.

Is there a way to define the column order?

Comment: I don't see an "accountid" in your entity code at all. The rest of the columns seem to match the described order.

Comment: @RichardHuxton It's `account` - typeORM seems to add the `id` suffix which I'm fine with. I believe it does this because of the `ManyToOne` relationship since that is a foreign key it adds the suffix to be clear: https://typeorm.io/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations